# equivalence of two complex integrals in Ahlfors Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

On page 131 (Chapter 4 section 3.3) of Ahlfors Complex Analysis he states:

The function w = f(z) maps [the closed curve] $\gamma$ onto a closed curve $\Gamma$ in the w-plane, and we find $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{dw}{w} = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$

I am having trouble seeing why this equality must hold. I suppose heuristically you could say let w = f(z), then $\frac{dw}{dz}$ = f '(z) so dw = f '(z)dz and since f(z) maps $\gamma$ into $\Gamma$ we get $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{dw}{w} = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$. Can somebody please supply me with a rigorous argument for this or explain why my heuristic reasoning is justified. Thanks.

Comment: The proof of the change of variable formula works the same way in complex analysis, ie. showing the primitives of the integrand are locally equal. Try making $w = f(z),dw = f'(z)dz, \frac{dw}{w} = \frac{1}{f(z)}f'(z)dz$ concrete in term of some parametrization $z = \gamma(t),dz = \gamma'(t)dt, w = \Gamma(t) = f(\gamma(t))$

Answer (score 0):

There is a condition for this: The map $f:\gamma \rightarrow \Gamma$ should be 1-1 and orientation preserving. For example, $z\mapsto z^2$ maps the unit-circle to itself but winds around twice; the integrals are not the same. Similarly for $z\mapsto 1/z$. When the condition is verified it amounts to a reparametrization of the closed curve $\Gamma$.